# Composer install fail on TFS Server

Tags: php, tfs, composer-php

We are running a Team Foundation Server (on premises) and as part of a build process it runs composer to install dependancies.  Sometime in the last week this process has started failing and I cannot figure out why.

Here is the console output from a failed run:

```
- Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.11.0): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (failed) 
Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (failed) 
Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (failed)  Failed to download symfony/polyfill-ctype from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/polyfill-ctype/zipball/82ebae02209c21113908c229e9883c419720738a" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Now trying to download from source
- Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.11.0): Cloning 82ebae0220


[RuntimeException]
Failed to clone https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-ctype.git via https, ss
h protocols, aborting.

- https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-ctype.git
Cloning into 'D:\agent\_work\3\s\vendor\symfony\polyfill-ctype'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-ctype.git/':
Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out

- git@github.com:symfony/polyfill-ctype.git
Cloning into 'D:\agent\_work\3\s\vendor\symfony\polyfill-ctype'...
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Here is part of the output from a successful run about a month ago:

```
2021-03-25T09:46:09.0972736Z Package operations: 28 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
2021-03-25T09:46:09.0972880Z - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.11.0): Loading from cache
2021-03-25T09:46:09.2716787Z - Installing webmozart/assert (1.4.0): Loading from cache
2021-03-25T09:46:09.5064411Z - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (1.0.1): Loading from cache
2021-03-25T09:46:09.7547542Z - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.4.0): Loading from cache
2021-03-25T09:46:10.0682007Z - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (4.3.1): Loading from cache
2021-03-25T09:46:10.4608228Z - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (3.0.1): Loading from cache
```

The successful run shows it is "loading from cache" rather than going to github.  I'm not that experienced with composer so I'm not sure what has gone wrong.  No settings on our TFS system have changed to my knowledge.

The server that this runs cannot access github as it is behind a firewall & proxy that block it.  But that has always been the case.

Does anyone know why composer would previously have been using a cache and is now trying to access github?

I have been searching the internet for hours for how the composer cache works but haven't been able to find anything that helps.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: _"server that this runs cannot access github"_ I'm confused as to how you expect it to work. How did the cache get filled?

Comment: @AlexHowansky that's a good question and I don't know!  I didn't actually set this up and I'm no expert on Composer.  All I know is that it has worked for years and now doesn't.  One possibility, although it's a guess, is that maybe there was a time in the past when this server could access github and that enabled the cache to be filled.  That would have been over a year ago though and it's been working fine until the last week or so.  Would the Composer cache expire?

Comment: Of course it would expire, that's how caches work -- but I doubt the expiry is greater than a year. And even if it is, you wouldn't have been able to grab new packages in that time, only previously-installed ones. I think it's pretty clear that your server's access was blocked only recently. You can confirm by looking at the create date on the files in the cache.

Comment: The code has been pretty stable and we haven't added new packages in the last year.  I've checked the location where I think the cache is stored (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Composer\files) and there is a folder in there for each package we are using, but there are no files in any of the folders.  The create date on the  folders is 25/03/2021, the time of the last successful build.

Comment: OK well, I think "how was it working before" is pretty irrelevant at this point. You'll either need to give the build server network access so composer can fetch what it needs, or you'll need to regularly create a pre-filled up-to-date cache on another machine and then install it on the build server.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  I'll see if it's possible to give it the access it requires. Weirdly I went back over every successful build in the history, going back to June 2019 and they all say "loading from cache".  I can't find a single one that hasn't used a cache.  Maybe someone did manually populate the cache.  Thanks again.

Comment: If that worked four weeks ago, but does no longer, you need to check what has changed. Also, this does not look related to programming to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this issue fixed by getting our corporate proxy updated to allow our build server to access github.

I still do not know how builds were working for so long without issue because to my best knowledge the build server would not have been allowed to access github for at least the last year.  I can only assume that either somebody manually setup the Composer cache or the server could, at some time, access github and then the cache just lasted for a very long time.

This was one of those confusing problems where nothing seems to have changed to explain it.  However I think something must have changed just a long time ago and the cache was masking it.

Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set variable `system.debug` to `true` to check the log to see whether you can get more information.
2. It seems the composer cache is removed on your agent machine recently. You would either make your agent machine access the internet, or install the package manually on the agent machine.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?